# Phone data security when plugged in to hotel power supply

Tags: security, power

is it true that only Apple chargers are secure from data theft from your phone through electrical systems such as in a hotel or coffee shop? I was told that you should never use a non-Apple phone or iPad charger because only Apple is proven to keep you secure from information being stolen while you are plugged in to a large non-residential power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no that is not true. However it is possible that bad actors have installed devices in some chargers to do nefarious things. The chances of you actually running across one of these? Probably slim but it depends on what kind of places you try to charge your phone. So no way of telling.

You can, however, protect yourself from such attacks by using a charging only USB/Lightning cable. Finding such cables is left up to your clever use of Google.

Comment: I've noticed (at least in Australia) that in many petrol stations (i.e. gas stations) it's easier to find USB/Lightning cables that only support charging. So that *may* be another option.